# fmt.Print in go routine *may* not output when master thread is loop

Tags: go, goroutine

The following code as is in https://play.golang.org/p/X1-jZ2JcbOQ

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
)
func p(s string) {
        fmt.Println(s)
}

func main() {
    go fmt.Println("1")
    go p("2")
    for {}   // infinite loop
}
```

prints 1 2 definitely in Windows with golang 1.11 but prints nothing definitely in Linux with golang 1.11.4. I can understand the former behavior but not the latter. Why is the go program not running non-master thread all the time?

Is there a reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go Playground runs with GOMAXPROCS=1. Try this on the playground:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "runtime"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
}
```

When you are running locally, you would perhaps have higher value of GOMAXPROCS.

Even on playground, you can see the printing work if you deschedule the main goroutine as below by introducing a Sleep [https://play.golang.org/p/QquMPZSd6kI]:

```
func main() {
    go fmt.Println("1")
    go p("2")

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    for {}
 }
```

OR

Change the GOMAXPROCS at start:

```
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
```

Comment: Nice catch! But why does master thread give its way to other threads when it meets time.Sleep instead of for{}?

Comment: @crukedsh for{} keeps the CPU busy while Sleep doesn't. Goroutines are cooperatively scheduled meaning they have to yield CPU on their own which they do in this case when hitting time.Sleep

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!